# Why must individual elements of a group have lockMovement=true?

Tags: fabricjs

I was trying to lock movement of a group, and found that I could not do so by just setting lockMovementX/Y on the group.

I was only able to lock down movement once every object in the group had lockMovementX/Y.

The group I'm using contains a line, 2 triangles, and an IText.

Here's an example of the group **not** being locked:

```
var object1 = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});
var object2 = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});

var group = new fabric.Group([object1, object2], {
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true
});
```

Example of group with locked movement:

```
var object1 = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true
});
var object2 = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true
});

var group = new fabric.Group([object1, object2], {
});
```

So, why must each object in a group have lockMovementX, and lockMovementY, set to true?

Comment: that is interesting. would you create a jsfiddle that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Sure thing, I'll update this question a little later.